# Press and swipe up to delete a UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, swipe, gesture

I'm wanting to make a `UIView` which acts similar to the iOS home button action where you can swipe a `UIView` with a gesture upwards until it is off the screen at which point it is deleted.

Although I can achieve the ability using a standard gesture, it does not give much UX feedback and would like to clone the ability to swipe upwards and make the `UIView` inline with the touch.

I'm wondering how to replicate or clone this ability where you can press and swipe upwards and the `UIView` will move in accordance to touch and delete.

thanks

Comment: Since swiping up opens the Control Center are you sure you want to utilize swipe up gestures within your app? I would consider rethinking your UI.

Comment: I mean from the uitextview